# Python: Invalid Syntax erroe

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and I am learning it. However, the code I have produced below is giving me errors like (invalid syntax). I think that the ValueError line is the problem. Can someone please fix this for me as its very frustrating. Thanks

```
def get_integer():
    while True:
        try:
            seven_integer = int(input("Please enter a seven digit integer: "))
            except ValueError:
                         print("Please enter a seven digit integer")
    continue
if 1000000 <= seven_integer
<= 9999999:
    return seven_integer
```

Comment: Is the indentation correct ?

Comment: The indentation as shown is definitely incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

So there are a few issues here.

When defining a function everything within it needs to be indented one tab in from the definition. Here your `if` statement is outside your function definition, so returning something makes no sense.

`continue` is used to break out of for or while loops, but you've not placed it inside one.

`if` statements need to be on the same line, so can't have a line break there.

You also appear to have two tab indentations before your print statement, when there should only be one.

Check out this indentation, it still won't do what you want it to do, but it'll make sense to the compiler:

```
def get_integer():
    while True:
        try:
            seven_integer = int(input("Please enter a seven digit integer: "))
        except ValueError:
             print("Please enter a seven digit integer")
        continue
    if 1000000 <= seven_integer <= 9999999:
        return seven_integer
```

If you're looking to get a 7-digit integer from the user then something like this may be more what you're after:

```
def get_integer():
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = input("Please enter a seven digit integer: ")
            seven_integer = int(user_input)
            if 1000000 <= seven_integer <= 9999999:
                return seven_integer
            else:
                print("That's not 7 digits...")
        except:
            print("That's not an integer...")

a = get_integer()
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted your code with appropriate indents, and it worked.

However, if you enter something that gives a value error it prints the message twice.

```
Please enter a seven digit integer: a
Please enter a seven digit integer
Please enter a seven digit integer:
```

I think the code below fixes your main issue. However, when I pasted this into the answer box, the browser formatted it like yours. :) I had to work to reformat it some.

By the way, I am using Python 3.6

```
def get_integer():
    while True:
        try:
            seven_integer = int(input("Please enter a seven digit integer: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a seven digit integer")
            continue
        if 1000000 <= seven_integer <= 9999999:
            return seven_integer
```